# How to enable maximize button in "desktop mode"

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need advice. Does anyone have experience in XAMARIN FORMS how to enable the button to maximize the application in "desktop mode". I've noticed, for example, that ZOOM or Chrome have this button enabled.

P.S. I test it on a physical device Lenovo Tab P11 Pro where the mod is called "productivity mode"

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not a xamarin related issue , we don't need to do anything in code , it is built-it function in system level .  please search the issue on lenovo forum like `Full screen (maximize) button is not working in tab P11` , it will come up some similar cases and you can try those possible solutions.

Comment: I tried all possible solutions: update the tablet firmware, reset the tablet to factory settings, but the problem still persists.
I don't think it's an OS bug. Some applications such as zoom, netflix, chrome, youtube and all applications from google are easy to maximize. I think it's a mistake for developers to forget about this area, because there are currently only a few products on the market that use the "productivity mode". https://i.imgur.com/hwjtRYr.jpg

I tried to add ResizeableActivity = true to the activity, it also doesn't work.

Comment: I found this article https://developer.samsung.com/samsung-dex/modify-optimizing.html which describes Samsung DEX and its implementation where it says: To enable multiple windows for Samsung DeX, paste this code into the Manifest file: resizeableActivity = "true".
According to this it should go to maximize the window but for Lenovo TAB P11 Pro it has no effect the application window can still not be maximized.